# Threads and reading writing memory is a byte or a bit safe?

Tags: multithreading, performance

I want to synchronize two threads. At the moment i am using double rotating dirty buffers that swap with a lock.

However it occurred to me i am only doing this to prevent dirty data from a write happening at the same time as a read. Can i store a flag in the most significant bit to convey data? or can i even go as far as whole byte.

For instance i can have an array of these and convey a lot of information in the form of bools. Reading and Writing is thread safe because the hardware can not read and write a single bit at the same time. So no garbage data.

Is this feasible? Is this the whole notion of atomic types.

Comment: Can you show some of your code please?  Maybe some pseudo code about what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: What? This is basic logic. No code required.

Comment: You'd need a memory barrier to do so at least. That depends on your programming language.

Comment: I completely forgot about out of order execution of the cpu. That is rather annoying. Wait do i still need it if i don't care if the bool is the wrong value in that cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I think that could work, when testing your flags you would want to do an atomic test and set or compare and swap operation to set the flag indicating a write was occuring. You would need to make sure you the appropriate keyword in your language (e.g. volatile or atomic possibly), or use some OS provided compare and swap functionality. Have a look at this for a good example:

http://drdobbs.com/embedded-systems/210604448?pgno=1

Comment: Not sure why i didn't read your answer properly before but i arrived at this using google. Good answer.

Answer (score 2):

You still need some sort of synchronization between your two threads.  Even if you did use a bit, byte, or word to indicate that the data was dirty, there is no guarantee that the rest of the buffer was updated at the same time.  You still need that memory barrier to update the buffers between the threads.

There is no such thing as an "atomic array".  You can read and write individual bytes or words atomically but the instant you have two of them, the operation is not atomic.  Your dirty flag can be updated atomically but if you have an additional buffers of information that are shared between threads then you need to synchronize to have the buffers be updated in the other thread's memory.

In addition, an array of atomic types (`volatile` or `Atomic*`) would be *much*, *much* less efficient because each access of an atomic value would cause a memory barrier to fire.  It is significantly more efficient to synchronize a single buffer with locks the way you have now.  That way a single (or multiple) memory pages can be updated at once as opposed to a large amount of small updates.

Also, in a producer/consumer model which I believe you have here, the consumer will need something to `wait()` on until the producer is finished and the producer will need to `wait()` on something to get a discarded buffer from the consumer.  Waiting on locks (or blocking queues -- see below) is an efficient way to accomplish this.

Here some other things to consider instead of

- Use a pair of [blocking queues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) so the consumer would wait on the queue and then add discarded buffers to a discard queue.  The producer would do the opposite.
- Have you taken a look at [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)?

Comment: I mean convey all the information from the thread in the form of these atomic single bit types. Just to clarify i would be replacing the buffers and it won't matter if only half of the atomic types have the right value in relation to an update cycle. Eg some of them might have old values because one thread is still writing the length of the atomic array.

Comment: You ruined your post with the edit.  The volatile keyword is not nearly good enough to provide the required memory barrier.

Comment: Oh, I see @HansPassant.  He edited his comment after I responded.  I thought for some reason he was talking about a single byte of information.  I'll remove my edit.  Thanks.

Comment: @user936509 There is no such thing as an "atomic array".  You can read and write individual bytes or words atomically but the instant you have two of them, the operation is not atomic.  Again, your dirty byte can be updated atomically but if you have an additional buffer of information shared, you need to synchronize to have the buffer be updated in the other thread's memory.

Comment: @Gray I meant an array of these atomic types. not an atomic array. confusing i know. With the emphasis on it being ok that some of the atomic types in the array may be dirty.

Comment: @user936509 An array of atomic types would be _much_ less efficient because each access of a `volatile` value would cause a memory barrier.  It is much more efficient to have a single buffer with locks the way you have now.  Then a single (or multiple) memory pages can be updated at once as opposed to a large amount of small updates.

Comment: @Gray you talk like you are implying a memory barrier is forced. All i am talking about is writing and reading a single bit in two different threads regardless of if an out of order instruction has changed its state.

Comment: Ah upon further research i have discovered this is used in lockless queue's and lockless ring buffers. Going to go implement that.

Comment: You can do this as much as you want @user936509.  However if you want this information to be shared between threads, then there needs to be some mechanism to synchronize the cache memory.  This is how threads share data.  If you want to share data then you _need_ a memory barrier.  You _want_ it.  Otherwise two threads could each be reading and writing to the same memory space and _never_ see the other's changes.  In modern multi-core, multi-cpu systems, each thread has it's own memory/cache space.  This is for speed.

Comment: Even with "lockless" queues and ring buffers there are synchronization points and memory barriers.  Have to be.  Otherwise they wouldn't be reentrant.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your processor architecture. If you have a 32-bit architecture, then you will have 32-bit values operated, if you have a 64-bit architecture, then 64-bit values. It doesn't matter if you're using byte, bit, or 16-bit char data types in your programming language. As long as they're smaller or equal to your processor's capacity (32 bit or 64 bit).

Comment: Also a good answer as you explained the sizes of atomic variables. Register size. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In modern CPUs (and not FPGAs / not microcontrollers / older systems that are 4 bit or less), the smallest block of data that can be written is 1 byte.

Even if you attempt to write a boolean datatype (1 bit) to a variable, it will still actually write an entire 8 bit char.

When the CPU writes a character, to RAM or a register it writes all 8 of those bits simultaneously. So the entire 8 bit byte is changed either all at once, or it's not changed all within the same clock cycle. There's no possibility for a thread to read an incompletely written or incompletely changed byte. So the byte is atomic.

When you write multiple bytes, there's no guarantee that the bytes are written same clock cycle (and you should assume that they are not), and you need to put something around that, either an atomic type like a single byte, or use some higher level construct in c++ to handle the locking for you. Otherwise, another thread or process can read that block of bytes when it's incompletely written or modified - and that's where you get data corruption.